# zip-a-folder Exclude a Directory

Tags: node.js, npm, zip

I am using [zip-a-folder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zip-a-folder) in Node.js. I have a directory called `dir`. Inside of `dir`, there are three directories, `a`, `b`, and `c`. I want to create a zip of `dir`, but I want to exclude `c` (I only want to zip `a` and `b`). How do I do that?

```
import { zip } from 'zip-a-folder';

await zip('/path/to/the/folder/dir', '/path/to/archive.zip');
```

If I can't do this with `zip-a-folder`, then what npm package should I use?

Answer (score 2):

use [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) and add exclusions with `glob` pattern's `ignore`

```
const fs = require('fs');
const archiver = require('archiver');
const archive = archiver('zip');
    
const inputPath = 'path/to/the/folder/dir';
const outputPath = 'path/to/archive.zip';
const exclude = [
    'c/**'
];

const output = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);

output.on('close', function() {
    console.log('done writing: ' + archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
});

archive.on('error', function(err) {
    throw err;
});

archive.glob(
    '**/*', {
        cwd: inputPath,
        ignore: exclude
    }
);

archive.pipe(output);

archive.finalize();
```